# boost binary_oarchive works differently for different compilers

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

I need to transfer data between client and server. When I moved server from Windows (msvc140) to Debian (gcc 64-bit) I've got a problem with my byte stream class based on `boost`. Their archives are different.

```
#include <string>    
#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/device/back_inserter.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/stream.hpp>

int main()
{
    std::string s;
    typedef boost::iostreams::back_insert_device<std::string> BackInsertDevice;
    typedef boost::iostreams::stream<BackInsertDevice> Stream;
    typedef boost::archive::binary_oarchive BinaryOArchive;

    Stream stream(s);
    BinaryOArchive ar(stream);

    ar << "qwer" << 10;
    stream.flush();

    int sz = s.size();
    // Windows (msvc140):    49
    // Debian  (gcc 64-bit): 57 
}
```

Both versions of `boost` are 1.61.0

Comment: Is your Windows 32-bit?

Comment: @Leon. Yes. It is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's documented. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/serialization/doc/todo.html#portablebinaryarchives

There is no portable archive in Boost itself.

You want to look at EOS Portable Archives: https://epa.codeplex.com/

They're very easy to drop in your code base and use instead of `boost::archive::binary_[io]archive`

Comment: Examples contain `#include <boost/archive/portable_binary_oarchive.hpp>` but I don't have this file in boost/archive.

Comment: That's because it's not part of boost. That's literally in my answer. I also link to the project for you to download in my answer

Comment: #include <boost/archive/shared_ptr_helper.hpp> - no such file. If replace to boost/serialization/shared_ptr_helper.hpp - error: 'boost::serialization::shared_ptr_helper': use of class template requires template argument list.

Comment: What are you doing? Just install those files alongside your source tree (say `epa/` and add them to your include search paths.

Comment: eos has 5 hpp files and doesn't have shared_ptr_helper.hpp.

Comment: That's why you **add** it. It's not a boost replacement. It's just an additional archive type.